# Ionic image not showing up on browser

Tags: image, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic project using Angular. I am using `img-src` to display my images and i'm certain the path is correct but they're not showing up on my browser.

`<img src="../Images/back.png" width = "16px" height=auto></img>`

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where in your project folder is your image `back.png` saved?

Comment: better than goung back with project levels like ../../etc..., u can just use assets/Images/back.png

Comment: @SurajRao it's in an Images folder inside the app folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your image in assets folder in your project and then write

```
<img src="assets/Images/back.png" width = "16px" height=auto/>
```